# How to turn a simple text expression into a mathematical expression in R

Tags: r, function, expression

Right now I am trying to solve a question concerning establishing a function to calculate the log of the moment generating functions in R. The required procedure is the user could input any random density function f(x) with the interval of the random variable. However, I have no idea how to let R identify the input string of the function expression, say "x^2-4*x", and turn it into a workable mathematical expression or say function. Can anybody help?

```
mgf <- function(expr, t, from=NULL, to=NULL){
moment <- NULL
    for (i in 1:length(t)){
        moment <- c(moment,integrate(exp(x*t[i])*(expr),lower=from,upper=to))
    }
return(moment)
}
```

This is the code I'm currently having. Obviously, it won't work. What I want is users can input an expression, like `x^2-4*x`, which is the value of expr, and then turn the expr into part of the function the `integrate()` function can evaluate.

Comment: if the question answers your need you can tick it!

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
library(functional)

mgf = function(stringFormula, t, from=NULL, to=NULL)
{
    f = function(x, i) exp(x*i)*eval(parse(text=stringFormula))
    sapply(t, function(u) integrate(Curry(f, i=u), lower=from, upper=to)[[1]])
}
```

The point is, you need to pass character string `x` as variable in your `stringFormula` argument:

```
mgf("x^2-4*x", 1:5, from=0, to=1)
#[1]  -3.281718  -6.791792 -14.652785 -32.698902 -74.976232
```

Comment: It says cannot find function Curry()

Comment: you have to import library `functional` since `Curry` is part of this package ... as it is written in my code ;)